# Azure Functions: Get full request URL including query string in a HTTP Trigger function

Tags: azure, query-string, azure-functions

Is there a way to get the full request URL, including the query string part, inside a Azure Functions HTTP Trigger Javascript function?

The req (and context.req) parameters do include the url without the query string in req.url, and the query string as key-value pairs inside req.query. But as far as I can see, it's not possible to directly access the full request url. It's also impossible to reconstruct the full URL with only the base url and the key-value object.

For example something like http://foo.azurewebsites.net/api/bar/baz?a=1&&&b=2&c=&d===5&e=&f=6&g

gets turned into

```
{
    url: '/bar/baz/',
    query: { 
        a: '1',
        b: '2',
        c: '\n\u0001d\u0012\u0003==5',
        e: '\n\u0001f\u0012\u00016',
        g: '\n\u0001a\u0012\u0003\n\u00011'
    }
}
```

Having access to the full request URL is required for building a proxy, a URL shortener etc. And since there is no official format for query strings, only conventions, it'd be nice to be able to handle all types of query strings just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook), you should be able to get it from `req.originalUrl`:

```js
module.exports = function (context, req) {
  context.log('HTTP trigger function processed a request: ' + req.originalUrl);
  context.done();
};
```

UPDATE from comments: apparently, this doesn't work on 2.0 runtime yet, but will eventually be supported: [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/2212).

Comment: Thanks Mikhail!

Unfortunately req.originalUrl does not include the query string, just the base url (same as req.url).

Comment: It does, I ran my function and got `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerJS1?code=mycode&test=test2` in the log

Comment: Interesting. What version of the runtime are you using? This might either be an issue with the 2.x runtime or the macOS CLI environment. Just created a new app and function to test and the query string is definitely not included in req.originalUrl. Thanks for steering me into the right direction though!

Comment: You're likely using Functions 2.0. After seeing your response, I've checked and it doesn't look like the original URL is properly formatted there. @Mikhail's answer is correct (the current behavior in 1.0) and will be the behavior in 2.0 as well. Opening an issue to fix and will share here

Comment: Opened this to track: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/2212